# empty database in datastage job

Tags: oracle, datastage

I have a datastage job composed with an oracle connector, transformer and oracle connector 
in the the first one there is an sql query :

```
SELECT
tcc.CDCIE, tcc.CDAPPLI, tcc.CDAPPLIORI, tcc.NUCONTRA, tcc.NUCONTRAUNIQUE, tcc.LBCONTRA, tcc.DTEFFCON, tcc.CDSITUATCON, tcc.DTSITUATCON, tcc.CDCATCON, tcc.IDINTERMAGI, tcc.IDINTERM, tcc.LBINTERM, tcc.IDINSPECTAGI, tcc.IDINSPECT, tcc.LBINSPECT,  
tcc.CDPAYTAX, tcc.CDCPTRES, tcc.CDPBCALC, tcc.CDPOSTAL, tcc.CDMODSIT, tcc.DTDERMOD, tcc.IDDELINC, tcc.IDDELINV, tcc.IDDELFMD, tcc.IDDELENC, tcc.TYPMOD, tcc.CDCAPTIF, tcc.CDCOAREA, tcc.DTDEBCOAREA, tcc.DTFINCOAREA,
tcc.CDREGSTAT, tcc.CDREGANX, tcc.CDFAMCOMPTA, tcc.LBFAMCOMPTA, tcc.CDSOCIETE, tcc.CDNATGAR, tcc.LBNATGAR , tcc.CDTYPCOA , tcc.LBTYPCOA , tcc.CDTYPREA , tcc.LBTYPREA , tcc.DTCRECON , tcc.IDCHEFREGAGI , tcc.IDCHEFREG, tcc.LBCHEFREG, tcc.ANNDEBREA, tcc.ANNFINREA, tcc.CDDELEGUE,
tcc.CDTYPOPRODUIT, tcc.FLAGMADELIN, tcc.DTDEBMADELIN, tcc.DTFINMADELIN, tcc.FLAMORTISSABLE,
tcc.DTSOUSCR,tcc.NUCONTRAUTIPER,tcc.NUCONTRAUTIORI,tcc.ACTIONSOCIALE
FROM TTEMP_CONTRAT tcc
WHERE tcc.CDAPPLI IN (13)

MINUS

SELECT
tcc.CDCIE, tcc.CDAPPLI, tcc.CDAPPLIORI, tcc.NUCONTRA, tcc.NUCONTRAUNIQUE, tcc.LBCONTRA, tcc.DTEFFCON, tcc.CDSITUATCON, tcc.DTSITUATCON, tcc.CDCATCON, tcc.IDINTERMAGI, tcc.IDINTERM, tcc.LBINTERM, tcc.IDINSPECTAGI, tcc.IDINSPECT, tcc.LBINSPECT,  
tcc.CDPAYTAX, tcc.CDCPTRES, tcc.CDPBCALC, tcc.CDPOSTAL, tcc.CDMODSIT, tcc.DTDERMOD, tcc.IDDELINC, tcc.IDDELINV, tcc.IDDELFMD, tcc.IDDELENC, tcc.TYPMOD, tcc.CDCAPTIF, tcc.CDCOAREA, tcc.DTDEBCOAREA, tcc.DTFINCOAREA,
tcc.CDREGSTAT, tcc.CDREGANX, tcc.CDFAMCOMPTA, tcc.LBFAMCOMPTA, tcc.CDSOCIETE, tcc.CDNATGAR, tcc.LBNATGAR , tcc.CDTYPCOA , tcc.LBTYPCOA , tcc.CDTYPREA , tcc.LBTYPREA , tcc.DTCRECON , tcc.IDCHEFREGAGI , tcc.IDCHEFREG, tcc.LBCHEFREG, tcc.ANNDEBREA, tcc.ANNFINREA, tcc.CDDELEGUE,
tcc.CDTYPOPRODUIT, tcc.FLAGMADELIN, tcc.DTDEBMADELIN, tcc.DTFINMADELIN, tcc.FLAMORTISSABLE,
tcc.DTSOUSCR,tcc.NUCONTRAUTIPER,tcc.NUCONTRAUTIORI,tcc.ACTIONSOCIALE
FROM TCOL_CONTRAT tcc
WHERE tcc.DTFINVALID = 999999
  AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TTEMP_CONTRAT ttemp WHERE ttemp.CDAPPLI = tcc.CDAPPLI AND ttemp.CDCIE = tcc.CDCIE AND ttemp.NUCONTRA = tcc.NUCONTRA)
  AND tcc.CDAPPLI IN (13)
```

when running the query in oracle it display the data but when trying to display the data in the first connector, the database is empty and 0 lines transfered when launching the job

your help will be appreciated 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if the logic in your query is at all working fine in datastage. Try applying the queries individually (i mean first only write the part before minus and second time the part after minus). 
Check if data is being pulled in both the scenarios. 
Also you can check if the 1st line is header is ticked. Maybe that can also cause an issue. 
Also you can check what kind of values are being pulled through your query.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also you can check if any previous truncate or delete operation is being applied in before/after job properties